# Conditional Switch for Indexed Types

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I would like to set up a conditional that triggers if the type passed into it has an index signature.  So far this is what I have:

```
type IsIndexed<T> = T extends {[key in string]: any} ?
    "type is indexed" :
    "type is not indexed";

const a: IsIndexed<boolean> = "type is not indexed";
const b: IsIndexed<{ [key: string]: number }> = "type is indexed";
const c: IsIndexed<{ prop: string }> = "type is not indexed"; // Type '"type is not indexed"' is not assignable to type '"type is indexed"'.
```

As you can see by the comment, there is a type error as TypeScript seems to consider object types without an explicate index signature to be a subset of those that do have one.

This makes sense - if I write a function and all it needs to run is an object with `string` keys and `boolean` values there's no reason an object that fits that shape with explicitly named keys can't be passed into it, but for my purposes this isn't enough.

***Is it possible to write a conditional type that identifies index signatures differently than explicitly named keys***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by testing whether `string` is a subtype of `keyof T` for the type `T`. If it is, then all strings are valid keys; if not, then the keys are restricted to a limited set of key names.

```js
type Indexed = { [k: string]: number };
type NotIndexed = { x: number, y: number };

type Detect<T> = string extends keyof T ? 'Indexed' : 'Not Indexed';

type TestIndexed = Detect<Indexed>; // 'Indexed'
type TestNotIndexed = Detect<NotIndexed>; // 'Not Indexed'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwgqBeKBvKBtAawC4oBnYAJwEs4BzAXRLgFcBbAIwgqgF8BuAFChIUAHIB7YPCSp0WXMiZtOFADRQQSjl16Ch4aABEIwCAGNgAHgAqAPkxlKNWlBSnEpKAQghxAMyhrKAB+KAByaRQ0MKgSMIlgWEQohDC9YWhrCHJI2QdjUwtLXLRbPigAegrwktT9ESzyBNr8k3MrZuTZMsrq+MkkmWiBIA)

Comment: Sort of blows my mind that this works - was fully ready to accept defeat on this one.  Thanks!